# Can I store the content of an ArrayList in a bean of Spring?

Tags: ajax, spring, hibernate, richfaces

Its my first post here so sorry if I do something badly.

My question is simple. I have a Bean Java class where I have a List attribute where I add values on it depending of which columns from a table I click on. The method to add values is a a4j:support tag to use Ajax in JSF and I have written it in the same bean class. When I click on the column for the first time, it store the data in the list correctly. But if I click again in another column, that list is initialized again as empty instead of adding the new values in the list with the previous values.

My question is: did the bean attributes reset if I launch a method more of 1 time or what I'm doing wrong?

Sorry for my bad English, hope you can understand it D:

Greetings.

EDIT: As you asked for, I will leave here the code.

EDIT2: Solved, only have to change @Scope("request") to @Scope("session") since "request" initialize the bean on every request and session initialize the bean only in the first session request. Thanks for all guys!

```
    <ui:composition template="/templates/main.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="title">TITLE</ui:define>

        <ui:define name="body">


           <table id="tablaFicheros" width="100%">
               <thead>
                    <th class="ficheros" >
                        <h:outputText  value="Categoría" />
                    </th>
                    <th class="ficheros" >
                        <h:outputText value="Subcategoría" />
                    </th>
                    <th class="ficheros" >
                        <h:outputText value="Nombre" />
                    </th>
               </thead>

               <tbody id="cuerpoTabla">
                       <c:forEach items="#{informesFicherosBean.listCategorias}" var="categoria" varStatus="status">
                            <tr id="filaCategoria#{categoria.idCategoria}">             
                                <td class="ficheros">

                                    <h:form>
                                        <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="listaSubCategorias" actionListener="#{ informesFicherosBean.abrirSubCategorias}">
                                            <f:attribute name="idCategoria" value="#{categoria.idCategoria}" /> 
                                        </a4j:support>
                                        <h:outputText value="${categoria.txtNombre}"/>
                                    </h:form>
                                </td>   
                            </tr>
                       </c:forEach>
               </tbody>

           </table>

             <rich:dataList value="#{informesFicherosBean.subcategoriasAbiertas}" id="listaSubCategorias" var="item" >
                <h:outputText value="#{item.txtNombre}" id="fichero#{item.id}" />
            </rich:dataList>
        </div>  

        </ui:define>    
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

Java class:

```
    @Service("informesFicherosBean")
@Scope("request")
public class InformesFicherosBean {

    /**
     * Log
     */
    protected static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(InformesFicherosBean.class);


    private List<InfInformesFicheros> listFicheros = new ArrayList<InfInformesFicheros>();


    private List<InfCategoria> listCategorias = new ArrayList<InfCategoria>();

    private List<InfCategoria> subcategoriasAbiertas;


    /**
     * Servicio
     */
    @Autowired
    private IInfInformesFicherosModelSvc infInformesFicherosModelSvc;

    /**
     * Servicio
     */
    @Autowired
    private IInfCategoriaModelSvc infCategoriaModelSvc;


    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
    }

    public List<InfInformesFicheros> getListFicheros() {
        if(listFicheros.isEmpty())
            return infInformesFicherosModelSvc.loadAll(); //Return all elements from this db table

        return listFicheros;
    }

    public void setListFicheros(List<InfInformesFicheros> listFicheros) {
        this.listFicheros = listFicheros;
    }

    public List<InfCategoria> getListCategorias() { //return all objects from categories db table

        if(listCategorias.isEmpty()){
            List<InfCategoria> categoriasActuales = infCategoriaModelSvc.listCategorias();
            setListCategorias(categoriasActuales);
        }

        return listCategorias;
    }

    public void setListCategorias(List<InfCategoria> listCategorias) {
        this.listCategorias = listCategorias;
    }

    public List<InfCategoria> getSubcategoriasAbiertas(){
        if (this.subcategoriasAbiertas==null){
            setSubcategoriasAbiertas(new ArrayList<InfCategoria>());
        }

        return this.subcategoriasAbiertas;
    }

    public void setSubcategoriasAbiertas(List<InfCategoria> subcategoriasAbiertas){
        this.subcategoriasAbiertas = subcategoriasAbiertas;
    }

    public void abrirSubCategorias(ActionEvent event){

//debugging here it always return getSubcategoriasAbiertas as an empty list

        Long idCategoriaParam = (Long) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("idCategoria");
        Integer idCategoria = idCategoriaParam.intValue();

        infCategoriaModelSvc.abrirSubCategorias(getSubcategoriasAbiertas(), getListCategorias().get(idCategoria - 1)); //add elements to attribute List "subcategoriasAbiertas"
    }

}
```

Comment: Send your code, please.

Comment: Great, I had edited the question with the code where the problem is, thanks